# How to add multiple checkboxes in PHP and mysql with different user id

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing a platform that allows me to enter presences at an event and I am stuck in one place. How can I load a series of checkboxes in order to change the user ID for each item?

A practical example, I have a table containing the name of all the people and next to it a checkbox once pressed submit php must upload the data for each user to the db.

Below the html form and the php script that manages the upload to the db.

'''php

```php
<?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM utenti";
                    $ris = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                    //$dati = mysqli_fetch_array($ris);
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ris)){
                        echo "<tr><td>".$row['nome']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['cognome']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row['squadra']."</td>";
                        echo "<td>
                        <input type='checkbox' name='presenza' data-toggle='toggle' data-onstyle='success' data-offstyle='danger' data-on='Presente' data-off='Assente' value='1'>
                        </td></tr>";
                    }
```

'''

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!empty($_POST['presenza'])){
        // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach($_POST['presenza'] as $selected){
        echo $selected."</br>";
        $sql="INSERT INTO presenze(id_utente,settimana,presenza) VALUES ('1','1','$selected')";
        if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
            echo "Records added successfully.";
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($conn);
        }
        }
        }
}
```

'''

Comment: Sorry, I added the html and php code

Comment: Start by removing `name="presenze"` in your form. It's probably conflicting with your checkboxes of the same name. Also, `mysqli_error($link)` won't work because it's not the same variable as you used in the query, being `$conn`. Edit: Which now you edited.

Comment: I had wrong html code, I modified it with the correct one. The first script populates an html table and displays name, surname and presence checkbox for each row. This happens for all the lines contained in the db. Once populated all, I select the attendance checkbox and send the form. But how do I for each row to indicate for which user id to add a row?

Comment: You will need to use a `WHERE` clause for this then. I.e.: `SELECT (column) FROM your_table WHERE X='abc'` type of thing.

Comment: Also, see about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 0):

One of the way to get relationship between a user and a checkbox is to use user ID (or whatever unique identifier you have in your tables structure) in checkbox name e.g.:

```
"<input type='checkbox' name='presenza_" . $row['user_id'] . "'>"
```

Then on the backend you can iterate over all post params with `presenza_` prefix and get user ID from it.

So your code will be a bit more sophisticated:

```php
foreach($_POST as $param_key) {
  // working only with params started with presenza_
  if (0 !== strpos($param_key, "presenza_")) { 
    continue;
  }

  $presenza_parts = explode("_", $param_key);
  $user_id = (int)$presenza_parts[1];
}
```

Keep in mind that checkbox field sends only value if it's `switched on` and sends nothing if it's `switched off`.